# Adding MAXDOP to Linq to Entities

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I was looking for linq to entities extension which allows to add OPTION(MAXDOP x) to the query generated. For queries I want to limit their SQL Server resources.

Something like:

```
Customers.WithMaxDop(2).Where(...) ..
```

Couldn't find.
Before I try to dig-in to create my own extension I wanted to ask you guys first for help - how would you suggest to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is query hint which cannot be added by extension method. You must either build whole new EF provider or wrap the query with the hint into database view and map the view as the new read only entity.

EF is abstraction on top of database (theoretically any database) - it is not supposed to offer you control over such DB details. If you want these details you must code them on database layer and only expose views or stored procedures to EF.

Comment: Hi, tnx for your reply. What about tricks like in this solution: http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx - catch the generated sql text then manipulate it by injecting the hint OPTION(..), and only then run the query.. though then I loose the result as entities.

Comment: That would be pretty big workaround and it will be the same like executing your own custom SQL query via `context.ExecuteStoreQuery` - you will lose functionality like eager loding. You can get SQL generated by casting your query to `ObjectQuery` and using `ToTraceString`. Be aware that EF sometimes creates really big queries so parsing and modifying such query can be very complex, error prone and slow operation.

Comment: Dang it everywhere I turn with EF I get shut down. I am querying data that the DBops guys really require (maxdop 2) or some kind of nolock. dang dang dang...

Comment: Here's an interesting article about MAXDOP and Cost Threshold for Parallelism. The latter may be a less heavy-handed solution: [http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2014/maximum-degree-parallelism/]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is now possible with EF Core 3.x.
You can "Intercept Database operetation" at a low level, before and/or after the operation. In the example provided by Microsoft, they added an hint at the end of the query.

```
command.CommandText += " OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)";
```

However, I don't know if this will occur for each and any operation, or if you can apply those interceptions only on selected commands.
More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/#interception-of-database-operations